# Add meta-data to a Qt property

Tags: c++, qt, metadata

I'm developing an application which displays items on a `QGraphicsScene`. These
items have properties, which I would like to display in a tree-view, if the
item is selected. If possible, I would like to stick with the property system
implemented by `QObject`. However, this does not fit all my needs because I need
to store some meta-data along the properties, e.g.

- a category used for grouping (e.g. "System properties" and "User properties")
- a tooltip text which is shown when the mouse hovers over the property in
  the tree-view.

Inspired by [Qt Property Browser](http://doc.trolltech.com/solutions/4/qtpropertybrowser/index.html) and by Qt's object framework, I have thought to
implement the following system:

1. All items in the scene are derived from `PropertyItem` (which itself inherits
   `QGraphicsItem` or `QGraphicsObject`). It contains
   the logic to get and set the value of a property.
2. Every class derived from `PropertyItem` has a static `MetaPropertyItem`.
3. A `MetaPropertyItem` holds instances of the class `MetaProperty` in order
   to store meta-data about the properties of such as the category, the
   tooltip string and the type of the property.
4. Whenever an item is selected in the scene, instances of the `Property` class
   are created for every `MetaProperty` from the associated `MetaPropertyItem`.
   These properties are then shown in the tree-view and deleted when the item
   is deselected.

The more I think about this design, the more I get the feeling that I'm doing
something wrong. It seems that I'm just duplicating what is already part of Qt:

```
PropertyItem     <--> QObject
MetaPropertyItem <--> QMetaObject
MetaProperty     <--> QMetaProperty
Property         <--> needs to be implemented
```

I also found this [bug ticket](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-17301), which proposes to add meta-data to a Qt property.
Unfortunately, it did not get any attention so far.

Looking for alternatives, I also stumbled upon `QMetaPropertyBuilder` which
will (probably?) be part of Qt 5. Unfortunately, documentation about this class is sparse
and what I understood from reading the sources it would not solve my problem.

**Thus, my question:** Is there actually a better way to achieve what I'm
looking for without re-implementing another Qt framework?

Comment: QMetaPropertyBuilder seems to be part of QML underlying code. It's probably not exposed on the C++ side. Also. I would just add a QMap<QString, QVaraintMap> to the object with the property name as the key. The property value and meta data can all be stored in the QVariantMap.

Comment: @StephenChu: Your approach sounds reasonable. I think I'll stick to it :)

Comment: Why don't you derive your displayed objects from QObject? Add standard Qt style properties to contain the information you need (tooltip text, etc.)